# Primefaces: Using multiple messages-components

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In our project we use Primefaces 6.2.17 and we currently have one [messages-component](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml?jfwid=e0880) that displays all our messages. Let's call this component *m1* :

```
<p:messages id="m1" showDetail="false" closable="true" escape="false">
    <p:autoUpdate/>
</p:messages>
```

In the backend, we create messages like this:

```
Faces.getContext().addMessage(null, Messages.createInfo("messageText"));
```

I would like to add an additional messages-component *m2* that is styled differently from the first and displays only messages from a certain source. All other messages should still be displayed by the *m1*. While looking through the documentation, I found the `for` attribute, which allows me to specifiy a key such that *m2* displays only messages of that key, like this:

```
<p:messages id="m2" for="messagesForM2" showDetail="false" showIcon="false"
            closable="true" escape="false" style="some styling...">
    <p:autoUpdate/>
</p:messages>
```

and

```
Faces.getContext().addMessage("messagesForM2", Messages.createInfo("messageText"));
```

This almost does what I want, *m2* does not display any messages that are intended for *m1* (messages without the key "messagesForM2"), however, all messages intended for *m2* are displayed by both *m1* and *m2*. I tried adding `globalOnly = "true"` to *m1*, but this causes *m1* to not display certain messages, e.g those produced when the user tries to save a form while a form-element with `required = "true"` is empty.

So my question is how can I send certain messages exclusively to *m2* while having all other messages send to exclusively *m1* ?